# Jsom not working when user is reader

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, mms

I am using following code to get terms from a termset in MMS. It is a office 365 solution and some of users is external users which have read permissions. The javascript doesn't work when user is external and has reader permission.(It is not an app but a usual JS file)

```
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var tSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(clientContext);
 var ts = tSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
 var termSets = ts.getTermSetsByName("MyTermSet", 1033);
 clientContext.load(termSets);
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args)
 {
      var navEnum = termSets.getEnumerator(); //it is empty for a reader
      ....
 }
```